# Mobile header available only on the main page

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, header, mobile-detection

On my website [clevervox.com](http://clevervox.com) I have a strange problem: My mobile menu and logo are visible only on the first page and on the other they disappeared and I couldn't find logic for this. My template is [Lightmart](http://demo.flexiblewebdesign.com/lightmart/). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the markup for the header isn't there at all, so we know it's not a CSS related issue.

I'm going to have a guess and say it's most likely 1 of 2 things:

#### 1:

The header is a module. Therefore you need to ensure it's assigned to every page. Open the header module in the **Module Manager**, go to **Menu Assignment**, then select **Show on all pages**

#### 2:

Your template has some funky code in the *index.php* which is telling it to only this this section on the homepage. It would be an extremely odd thing for a developer to implement, however I've seen it done before.

Comment: Agree with @Lodder, just want to add the fact that from CSS via Firebug is visible that template used is LightMart from FleXible and on it's Demo Page http://demo.flexiblewebdesign.com/lightmart/ it is clear that both Logo and mobile menu are visible on all pages, not only on homepage. So, you must have misconfigured something in template config.

Comment: Yes, the module is  assign to all pages and index.php is the same as an our old website (which is without menu problem), so I think and index.php is not problem. Maybe left some settings in template, for which I still don't have idea.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the regular header and the mobile header (both menu and logo) are separate modules. The regular (full width) header is hidden on screen sizes below 768px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 569px) {
   #headerbar, #headerbar, #menubar, #totop-scroller {
       display: none;
   }
}
```

Check if you have a module that is visible only on your home page.